# Data Processing In C# - Best Approach?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am still on a learning curve in C# and SQL Server so please forgive my ‘greeness’.

Here is my scenario:

I have an EMPLOYEE table with  10,000 rows. Each of these employees has transactions in a TRANSACTIONS table.

The transaction table has the salary elements like Basic pay, Acting allowance, Overtime hours etc. It also has payroll deductions like advance deductions, some loans (with interest), and savings (pension, social security savings etc.

I need to go through each employee’s transactions and compute taxes, outstanding balances on loans, update balances on savings, convert hours into payments/deductions and some other stuff.

This processing will give me a new set of rows for each employee, with a period marker (eg 2013-04 for April 2013). I need to store this in a HISTORY table for future references.

What is the best approach for processing the entire 10,000 employee table and their transactions?

I am told that pulling the entire table into memory via readers is not good practice and I agree.

Do I keep pulling an employee from the database, process their transactions, and commit the history to the database? And pull the next and so forth?

Too many calls to the back end?

(EF not an option for me, still doing raw SQL in ADO.NET)

I will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: If you only need to calculate this tax infrequently, why not write a Sql server stored procedure to do it? Then your c# program can read the "tax history" table, or initiate another recalculation (calling the Sproc) if need be...

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't perform the data manipulation wholly within the database rather than involving .Net?

Comment: @Will A: I will be having over 50 DBs for different payroll cients. The processing in a monthly thing. So in my opinion, I thought to have the processing on the client side.

Comment: @b.oa this is not a good reason to do it on the client side. Not with the information presented so far. You need a period marker, taxes, outstanding balance and a few other things, and you need to store the results in a table? A single DB query can do this, be it in a stored procedure or sent from the application. No information you have provided so far makes a good argument for pulling all the data to the client application, doing the computation there, and sending back the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10000 rows is not much. Memory could easily handle that if there's not some enourmous varchar or binary columns. Don't feel completely locked by good practice "rules".

On the other hand, consider a [stored procedure](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38682/Overview-of-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure). Then all processing will be done locally on the server.

edit: if neither of the above is an option, try to stream your results. For example, when reading your query save each row in a `ConcurrentQueue` or something like that. Before you execute the query, start another thread or a `BackgroundWorker` which checks the queue for new items and saves back results simultaneously on another `SqlConnection`. Work will be done when query is done AND the queue has `Count` 0.

Comment: My app will be dealing with over 50 different DBs (identical though) but each DB will be for one client on account. So sp maintenance may be an issue -- I thought maybe I should have the processing login in client side.

Answer (score 1):

Check out using `ROW_NUMBER()`.  This can be used by programs to allow large tables to  be essentially browsed using 'x' number of rows at a time.  You could then conceivably use this same method to batch your job over, say, 1000 rows at a time.

See [this](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10434/sql-server-server-side-paging-with-rownumber-function.aspx) link for more information.

Comment: I have checked the link. I will do some tests and see if it fits my case. Thanks nonetheless.